# Should dispose a rx-java Maybe?

Tags: rx-java2

If I have this rxjava chain:

```
Observable.create { ... }
  .firstElement()
  .subscribe( {...}, {...})
```

After experimenting and looking at the sources, it looks like `firstElement()` automatically dispose the up stream (which makes sense), so I don't have to care about it. Is that right?
Ok then. My question is, should I dispose the Maybe returned by `firstElement()`?
I put a `.doOnDispose()` callback after `firstElement()` and checked that it doesn't happen automatically. Does that mean that I shouldn't care? If a `Maybe` can emit no more than one item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** You should don't care.

**Longer answer:** `doOnDispose()` is only called when Observable is disposed explicitly (by `disposable.dispose()`) but it will not be invoked when Observable calls `onComplete()`. If you want to check it by yourself instead of `doOnDispose()` you should us `doFinally()`.

Peace!